# i want my buttons to be sunkenvfor 3 seconds, and i want an if/else statement to detect my buttons if they are sunken

Tags: if-statement, tkinter, button

i have tried using sleep and after, but they stop the whole program, meaning no other buttons can be pressed.
i want the if/else statement to stop the entire program if all 4 buttons are pressed down, and the buttons to stay down for 3-5 seconds, like a sort of useless box/machine. after that i though about using

```
if target1.config(relief=sunken)
```

but that doesnt work since it cant detect the button being sunken like that

```
def target1():
    global target1
    tk.Button()
    target1 = tk.Button(boxroot, command=move1,text="exit")
    target1.place(x=0, y=0)


def move1():
    target1.config(relief=SUNKEN)
    target1.config(relief=RAISED)
    xlist1 = list(range(0, 900))
    ylist1 = list(range(20, 200))
    x1 = random.choice(xlist1)
    y1 = random.choice(ylist1)
    target1.place(x=x1, y=y1)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to sink buttons for 3 to 5 seconds and if all have been sunken then do something, well this should do it, explanation is in code comments:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random


# list for storing references to the buttons
buttons = []


def press(button):
    # if the button is already pressed exit this function
    if button['relief'] == 'sunken':
        return
    # on press sink the button
    button.config(relief='sunken')
    # schedule after 3 - 5 seconds to raise the button
    button.after(random.randint(3, 5) * 1000,
                 lambda: button.config(relief='raised'))
    # check if all buttons have been sunken in that button list
    # and if they are do stuff
    if all(b['relief'] == 'sunken' for b in buttons):
        print('All buttons are pressed')


root = tk.Tk()

# creating 4 buttons in a loop
for _ in range(4):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text='Press me!')
    # configuring button with command so that the button itself can be
    # passed as an argument
    btn.configure(command=lambda b=btn: press(b))
    btn.pack()
    # add the button to the button list
    buttons.append(btn)

root.mainloop()
```